# Line break for media-query only?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Is there any solution for line break when screen resolution is small instead of `<br>`? Because `br` break line all the time.

Here is my code:

`<h2>I create unique, clean sites that are easy to navigate.<br>All my works comply with web</h2>`

I think CSS3 may have solution of this issue.

Is there any solution for this `<br>`, because the line break only needed when page on mobile.

Comment: I love 'All my works comply with web' :-)

Comment: wrap the second sentence into a span element, then assign `display: block` to the element at a given width. But I'd like there were a cleaner solution than this or using a <br>

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could simply add a class to the BR tag and set it to be display:none by default.

Then in your mobile media query set it to "display: static"

I've suggested static rather than block because I don't think that a BR tag is display block by default so probably best to simply go with static.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/iyamum/2/edit Ok, it works and with "mobile first approach" there's no need to reverse the display - just remember to put a space between the dot and `<br>`

Comment: `display` doesn't have property value called `static`, so it's better to use `block`. For reference http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_display.asp. But I am still wondering what's the default display property for `<br />`

Comment: @Syed - A few pieces on position static: http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101 https://css-tricks.com/what-if-there-was-no-position-static/ https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: For info, I ended up using "display: unset"

Comment: @Syed It's `display:inline` for a `<br />`

Answer (score 7):

If using Bootstrap:

```
<br class="visible-xs">
```

Comment: yes, it is one of the best answer if bootstrap tagged in the question

Comment: In answer to my own question: no. see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/migration/#responsive-utilities -- `Rather than using explicit .visible-* classes, you make an element visible by simply not hiding it at that screen size`

Answer (score 5):

You could just use floats, that way you never need to even think about where the snapping point needs to be. It either displays both next to each other, or instantly snaps to the next line if they don't fit.

```
span {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0.4em;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e4mWK/

Comment: This is a nice clever clean solution!

Comment: In complement to Christian's answer, you can also use the CSS white-space:nowrap; property to wrap pieces of text that you don't want to line-break. I.e a slogan, a proper name etc.

Answer (score 2):

Mobile first, hide the `br`, then set the display back to `initial` on larger screens:

```
<br class="hide desktop-show">
```

the css:

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 64em) {
    .desktop-show {
        display: initial;
    }
}
```